# How do I change the delimiter used in CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter, separator

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2219: character maps to <undefined

I would appreciate your help

Comment: pandas - `pd.read_csv("employment.csv").to_csv('emp.txt', sep='|', index=False)`

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the delimiter. You are setting the delimiter correctly. The error tells you that there is a decoding issue. The "w" mode is actually "wt" which writes text and requires a codec. You can ignore this by changing the mode to "wb" in order to write the file but it still won't help you whenever you eventually need the decoded string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [CSV Examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

Since [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is used to open a CSV file for reading, the file will by default be decoded into unicode using the system default encoding (see [locale.getpreferredencoding()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding)). To decode a file using a different encoding, use the encoding argument of open:

```py
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

The same applies to writing in something other than the system default encoding: specify the encoding argument when opening the output file.